# DOMPDF check if it's a new page

Tags: php, dompdf

Is there a way to tell if you're on a new page when generating the PDF? Sort of like what the `<thead>` does when rendering the table on the next page. I've checked the inline PHP script but it does not support HTML. Any possible options?

Comment: What, exactly, do you need to do when you reach a new page? There's some difficulty around this because inline script is parsed separately from the HTML.